# How to remove and append elements from a parent iframe using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I have this object in Javascript using JQuery:

```
NavigationBar.objNavBar = window.frames.F_MAIN.document.getElementById('navBar');
```

When I try to change the css like this:

```
$(NavigationBar.objNavBar).css("display", "block");
```

It works as expected, but when I try to remove or append html to it, for example:

```
 $('ul li', NavigationBar.objNavBar).remove();
```

I get a "Permission denied" exception. Both iframes are in the same domain, it's actually an old application that was created using iframes.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you do this instead? -> `$('ul li', NavigationBar.objNavBar).css("display", "none");`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I need to remove the li and create another thing in there.